Repository Missing In Gradle Plugin 1.5.1 Version
We don't see any repository for below Gradle version i.e., 1.5.1, but where as we see for other 2 plugin versions.
Any suggestions w.r.t 1.5.1 version ?
plugins.gradle.org/m2/net/saliman/gradle-properties-plugin/1.5.1/
Contains Repository for below versions:
plugins.gradle.org/m2/net/saliman/gradle-properties-plugin/
plugins.gradle.org/m2/net/saliman/gradle-properties-plugin/1.5.2/
Need repository for below gradle version where we can find.
plugins.gradle.org/m2/net/saliman/gradle-properties-plugin/1.5.1/
Received below error while trying to deploy the code.

What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'net.saliman.properties', version: '1.5.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:


Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'net.saliman.properties:net.saliman.properties.gradle.plugin:1.5.1')
Searched in the following repositories:
Gradle Central Plugin Repository

Please try to contact that Stevealiman about putting 1.5.1 back out there....
Also, when tried using stacktrace for gradle init, getting below error.

What went wrong:
Plugin [id: 'net.saliman.properties', version: '1.5.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:


Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'net.saliman.properties:net.saliman.properties.gradle.plugin:1.5.1')
Searched in the following repositories:
Gradle Central Plugin Repository


Try:


Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
Run with --scan to get full insights.


Exception is:
org.gradle.api.plugins.UnknownPluginException: Plugin [id: 'net.saliman.properties', version: '1.5.1'] was not found in any of the following sources:


Gradle Core Plugins (plugin is not in 'org.gradle' namespace)
Plugin Repositories (could not resolve plugin artifact 'net.saliman.properties:net.saliman.properties.gradle.plugin:1.5.1')
Searched in the following repositories:
Gradle Central Plugin Repository
at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.resolveToFoundResult(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:238)
at org.gradle.plugin.use.internal.DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.lambda$resolvePluginRequests$3(DefaultPluginRequestApplicator.java:168)
at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:207)
at org.gradle.util.internal.CollectionUtils.collect(CollectionUtils.java:201)

